# loop thru contents of a file in batch under windows 7

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

Okay, I am sure I am not the only one who asked this question before but with my limited understanding of batch file command syntax, I am at a loss. Clicking on the suggested answers before penning this question, did not get me to where I want.

Here is my situation at hand:

Everyday, I am given a bunch of URLs to launch and check for if a certain string is displaying on each of these pages in a certain period of time (some very poorly written web app creates the content of these pages) The number of URLs I am given, varies wildly from day to the next. The only constant is the file name the URLs come in.

So, I need to loop through the URLs in this file slowly such as :

(this is the Linux/Bash representation of what I want to do)

```
for URL in `cat URLlistFILE.txt`
do
  /usr/bin/chrome $URL
  sleep 30
  touch semaphore file 
# an AHK script checks for the existence of semaphore file on the windows side
# when it is present, it does a screen scraping and search for the string
# then remotely deletes the semaphore file and reports the findings.
  sleep 30
done
```

so, under batch process I will have some sort of a foreach loop and launch my command as such:

C:\Users\MyUSER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %URL%

but how will I construct the for loop and assign each line to variable named URL under batch mode

And yes I can do the whole thing in Linux and not nned any batch file but this will be handed out to a lower level support who has no understanding of running any Linux desktop, likes of GNOME, KDE or others. So it has to be a batch file and run on a win7 platform.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't use batch for this. Languages like PowerShell or VBScript are far better suited for this kind of task.

PowerShell:

```
$urllist    = "C:\path\to\urllist.txt"
$teststring = "..."

Get-Content $urllist | % {
  $content = (Invoke-WebRequest $_).RawContent
  if ( $content -match $teststring ) {
    Write-Host "$_`tOK" -ForegroundColor green
  } else {
    Write-Host "$_`tNOK" -ForegroundColor red
  }
}
```

VBScript:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

urllist    = "C:\path\to\urllist.txt"
teststring = "..."

For Each url In Split(fso.OpenTextFile(urllist).ReadAll, vbNewLine)
  Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
  req.open "GET", url, False
  req.send

  If req.status = 200 Then
    If InStr(req.responseText, teststring) Then
      WScript.Echo url & vbTab & "OK"
    Else
      WScript.Echo url & vbTab & "Not OK"
    End If
  End If
Next
```

Comment: your answer might be an elegant one but since I am having hard time understanding the simpler batch commands, when it comes to your code snippets, I am totally clueless. Not if, but when they ask me to change my code, I want to have a fighting chance. Hence, my heart is pretty much set on batch. But thanks anyways.

Comment: also, I am hearing from everyone that powershell commands are included in win7 command prompt automatically. How can I test the validity of this claim ?

Comment: @Mel_Burslan PowerShell is included with Win7, but you can't run PowerShell cmdlets directly in `CMD`. You can run `powershell.exe` in `CMD`, though, e.g. `powershell -Command "Write-Host 'foo' -ForegroundColor red"` or `powershell -File C:\path\to\script.ps1`. As for the simplicity of batch commands: it's because they're so simple that trying to do advanced stuff with them becomes really complicated/awkward.

Comment: @Mel_Burslan For a batch file, this task will need VB script anyway or a tool like WGET to download the web pages, and then search them.  It will be further complicated by adding your nebulous time frame requirement - so a batch script that performs this task is likely to be very convoluted and also require a (free) third party program or VBS.